# WARNING: Collections containing mixed types can not be stored in properties

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to upload data in to neo4j DB using LOAD CSV and facing below error.

> WARNING: Collections containing mixed types can not be stored in
>   properties.

My csv file is containing around 10000 records . Now how do I find the problematic record.

Comment: It would really help if you added your entire LOAD CSV query, as well as some description (hopefully a sample) of the CSV itself.

Answer (score 0):

I could not share the actual csv file due to privacy issue.

Please ensure that each field from CSV is enclosed in double quotes .

Sample File is mentioned here. First Line represents header and Second Line shows actual data.

**"id","code","user_track"**

**"100","ABC123","USER_REGISTRATION"**